# Dequeuing reusable cell in Swift 3 is incredibly slow

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

Dequeuing a cell is taking 0.5-1.0 seconds which means that my UITableView takes more than 2-3 full seconds to load even though it only has 4 rows.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cellid = "NumberCell"
    var isnumber = true
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cellid = "TextCell"
        isnumber = false
    }
    
    NSLog("before dequeue \(indexPath)")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellid, for: indexPath) as! TextfieldTableViewCell
    NSLog("dequeued")
    
    // ...
    
    return cell
}
```

The NSLog() statements directly before and after show that the dequeue takes from `07.47` to `08.38`.

> 2017-07-25 22:07:07.471898-0700 myapp[10209:4507471] before dequeue [0, 0]
>
> 2017-07-25 22:07:07.679715-0700 myapp[10209:4507471] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>
> 2017-07-25 22:07:07.683843-0700 myapp[10209:4507471] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
>
> 2017-07-25 22:07:08.386960-0700 myapp[10209:4507471] dequeued

The cell is very simple. It just has a UILabel and a UITextField and the UITextField has an Editing Changed action. That's it.

[image]

What the heck could possibly be causing it to take SO long to dequeue a cell? Is it those other two system NSLog()s about the System group container?

It makes my app almost unusable because when I try to segue to this view controller the app appears to lock up for 2-4 seconds while it's setting up the 4 rows.

I've made hundreds of UITableViewControllers in Objective-C and I've never had this problem. Is there something weird about Swift 3 that I'm missing?

Comment: are you using `Nested ViewControllers` ?

Comment: Do you have examined the code with the time profiler in instruments?

Comment: **Go to Xcode -> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme
In the Environment Variables, add OS_ACTIVITY_MODE as name and disable as value** Just give a try this and let me know

Comment: it might not seem obvious and necessary. But write your code inside DispatchQueue.main.async and let me know if it improves the performance. Put all your  dequeueReusable code inside this. Please let me know, if it works or not.

Answer (score 2):

> 2017-07-25 22:07:07.679715-0700 myapp[10209:4507471] [MC] System group
>   container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is
>   /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>
> 2017-07-25 22:07:07.683843-0700 myapp[10209:4507471] [MC] Reading from
>   public effective user settings.

⚠️  This is a log from `OS Level`. which delay in dequeuing your `UITableCell`

You can disable unwanted log in `xcode` . like below

1- From Xcode menu open: `Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme`

2- On your Environment Variables set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` in the value set `disable`

[image]

You will face this problem only when you are debugging the app .
 this will run fine on real device .

Comment: The problem DID happen on device. It didn't have to do with the sim or the run scheme. It was a code flaw, I finally found it.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the problem and it was entirely my fault. I was accidentally requesting first responder on every field.

For convenience, I had overridden `setSelected(_:animated:)` so that if I touched the row that row's textfield would become first responder (just in case I tried to tap on a field and missed). The problem was that I forgot to put an if statement around the `becomeFirstResponder()` call.

Bad code:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    self.textfield.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

After dequeuing a cell it would set it to selected=false by default which would cause it to try to become first responder. It was a dumb mistake on my part.

Here's what I intended to do:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    if selected {
        self.textfield.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any problem with this piece of code. And I don't think the `dequeue` code really lasts for so long unless you're missing some important issues in your code. If your table view is as simple as you said, that wouldn't take so long. But to debug that, you must consider these points:

- NSLog is not a trustworthy timer for checking `dequeue`'s duration. You should use the code below to calculate the time accurately:

  let start = CACurrentMediaTime()
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellid, for: indexPath) as! TextfieldTableViewCell
  let finish = CACurrentMediaTime()
  print("dequeue time:(finish - start)")
- If the `dequeue` time is acceptable, your performance issue is not caused by it.
- If the `dequeue` time is still not acceptable. One reason makes sense is that you have only four rows of your tableview and none of them are higher than the tableview, so tableview is not going to use the cell from the buffer but going to create a cell from the bottom up. And this operation is far more time-consuming than using the cell from the buffer. But this process is inevitable because every app using tableview will encounter it. Therefore, you should consider if your simulator(Assumed you're using a simulator) is too slow to run your app. Because the speed between simulator and real iPhone is quite different.